# Interrupt (SIGINT) perl script from perl script running under apache

Tags: apache, perl, signals, interrupt

I have a perl script running as root that monitors a serial device and sends commands to it. Under apache, I have another perl script that displays a gui for the controlling 'root' script.

I'm trying to interrupt via sigint and sigusr1 the root perl script from the gui perl script but get operation not permitted, probably as one is root the other is not.

I basically want the gui to be able to tell the controlling root script to pass some command to the serial device.

If I run the gui script from the cmd line as root it can successfully signal the root script

I'm not sure where to go from here, any suggestions on methods to interrupt a root script when not running as root? calling seperate "signal" script as shown:

```
     @cmds = ("perl /var/www/signal.cgi", "$perlSerialPID", "test");
     if (0 == system(@cmds)) {
         # code if the command runs ok
         print "system call ok: $?";
     } else {
        # code if the command fails
        print "not ok $?";
     }
     # try backticks
     $output = `perl /var/www/signal.cgi $perlSerialPID test`;
     print "<br>:::$output";
```

signal.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$pid = $ARGV[0];
$type = $ARGV[1];

if($type eq "test"){
 if(kill 0, $pid) {
   print "perl-serial $pid running!";
 }else{
   print "perl-serial $pid gone $!";
 }
}elsif($type eq "USR1"){
  if(kill USR1, $pid) {
   print "perl-serial interrupted";
  }else{
   print "perl-serial interrupt failed $!";
  }
}else{
  print "FAILED";
}
```

Comment: Make a script that sends the signal.  Use sudo to call that script as root.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=742855

Comment: As mentioned above the gui script is run under apache, how do you then use sudo to call it as root as you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [named pipes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Named-Pipes) for IPC.

   The downside is that you'll have to retrofit your main script to read from the named pipe as event driven process.
2. Similar in concept to above (with the same downside), but use [sockets](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Sockets%3A-Client%2FServer-Communication) for communication.
3. Create a separate "send a signal" script that's called via a system call from your UI, and make that new script [SUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) and owned by root - in which case it will execute with root's permissions.

   Downside: this is **ripe** for security abuse so harden this very carefully.

Comment: I'll give the unsecure wrapper script a go as I really want to interrupt rather than poll or check a file/pipe at regular intervals

Comment: When you say sepperate script, did you mean a perl script as I've done that and it's still operation not permitted. Code shown above

Comment: I ended up adding www-data to sudo and calling the signal script via 'sudo perl /path/to/signal.cgi' passing any commands via a UNIX Socket. Interrupt tells the script to read and action any cmds sent via the socket as I can't have blocking the script while reading the pipe.